# What does grep do when a directory or file isn't added

Tags: bash, grep

I've been using the egrep command a lot lately (just out of preference over grep) and I have noticed a behaviour that I don't fully understand.
When I run the following command in my home directory:
`egrep -r "main" *`
it does what I expect and returns all of the lines and respective files that contain "main".

Although if I enter:
`egrep -r "main"`
and forget to put the star at the end, it seems to just hang forever.
I'm hoping someone might be able to shed some light as to why this is and what it is doing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's waiting for input from `stdin` because you didn't specify a filename, from the `grep` manpage:

```
NAME
   grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern

SYNOPSIS
   grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]
   grep [options] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]

DESCRIPTION
   Grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files
   are named, or the file name - is given) for lines containing a
   match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.
```

Answer (score 4):

grep (or egrep) needs to know what file(s) to search.  By including the `*`, you're telling it to search in all files in the current directory.

If you don't include the `*`, it doesn't know where to look, so it awaits your input, and will prompt you for input to search (type it in, then press ctrl+d to terminate standard input mode).

This behavior is not unique to grep.  Any command that requires input wants that input to come from a file or from standard input (stdin).

stdin data can come from a pipe or it can be typed in manually at the prompt after entering your command (which is what you were seeing when you thought it was hung).  As i mentioned, pressing Ctrl+D will get you out of that input mode.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't supply the path so grep waits on `stdin` for data.

Example with path:

`egrep -r "pattern" .` <- search in current directory and subdirectories

`cat file | egrep "pattern"` <- search in data from pipe